# Como exportar dados de um database Oracle 11 e importar num Oracle 10?

Tags: oracle, importação, exportação, oracle10g

Estou tendo problemas em exportar dados de um Oracle 11 para outro Oracle na versão 10. Tentei copiar o binário `exp` da maquina velha pra nova mas como são arquiteturas distintas (32/64 bits) não funcionou.

Eu li que o `Data Pump Export` é capaz de gerar dump compatível com versões anteriores mas ainda não consegui obter um resultado adequado.

Eu gostaria de executar a partir da linha de comando na Shell do Sistema Operacional (bash) sem criar procedure PL-SQL pois desta forma é mais facil documentar..

Alguma dica ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Exportando** na console com **Data Pump**

Você pode exportar (na maquina com Oracle 11) assim:

```
expdp system directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR schemas=seu_schema version=10.2
```

O nome do directory DATA_PUMP_DIR é obtido via comando SQL abaixo:

```
select * from dba_directories
```

Por acaso `DATA_PUMP_DIR` é o nome padrão mas o comando SQL acima deve ser executado para verificar se realmente está configurado desta forma na sua instalação.

**Exportando** na console com **Data Pump**

Você pode importar (na maquina com Oracle 10) assim:

```
impdp seu_schema directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR schemas=seu_schema
```

Observe que não precisa citar o nome do arquivo DMP pois ele atribui o valor `expdat.dmp` por padrão. Para verificar isso basta listar o conteudo do diretório, aquele apresentado quando você executou o comando `select` acima.

Por exemplo:

```
ls -lA /usr/lib/oracle/xe/app/oracle/admin/XE/dpdump
```

Não esqueça de copiar o arquivo DMP da maquina onde foi feito o export para a outra caso as duas versões de Oracle estejam instaladas em maquinas diferentes.